# Drop row numbers in R tibble

Tags: r, row, dt, row-number, tibble

How do I drop the row numbers when displaying R tibble through the DT package?

The `options = list(rownames = FALSE)` argument doesn't seem to work, I also "made up" `options = list(rownumbers = FALSE)` and that didn't work. I messed around with things like `select(2:everything())` but that did not work either. Maybe piping in `remove_rownames()` at then end will work... it does not, or perhaps `as.data.frame()` piped at the end... Nope.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
datatable(mtcars %>% head() %>% as_tibble(), options = list(rownames = FALSE))
```

[image: tibble with row numbers]

Comment: See `help("datatable")`. There is a `rownames = TRUE` default argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
datatable(mtcars %>% head() %>% as_tibble, rownames = FALSE)
```

You just need to rearrange the parenthesis, so that the `rownames` value is changed for `datatable` and not for the `as_tibble` call.

[image]